# Enable proprietary driver option disappeared after enabling it for AMD ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4330

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati, graphics, fglrx

I've been struggling with this a while. I have an older Acer Aspire 5810T with a AMD ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4330 inside it. I've disabled the switchable option and am now only running the HD4330 card, but I'm having trouble with the driver.

I'm running XUbuntu 12.04.5 and I've installed the legacy catalyst 13.1 driver which I manually downloaded from the AMD/ATIs website.

All good so far, it installs fine, except it says "loki_setup (null)". Don't really know what that means but dont think it matters very much.

All right, so I have the AMD Catalyst center installed and I can start games like Dota 2 which I couldn't before (Although the performance is way worse than when I used to run Windows 7. Really not playable honestly) - but now suddenly a Proprietary Driver shows up in the Additional Drivers app. Note that before installing the Legacy 13.1 thingy there was nothing there. Further it says that it's not enabled, so I try to enable it. That seemingly works, and it asks me to reboot - which I do. Now when I fire up Additional Drivers again, its gone. I can't remember exactly, but the name was something like

> FGLRX ATI/AMD ...

Also I can't start the AMD catalyst control centre anymore, and I get the error:

> There was a problem initializing Catalyst Control Center Linux edition. It could be caused by the following.
>
> No AMD graphics driver is installed, or the AMD driver is not functioning properly. Please install the AMD driver appropriate for you AMD hardware, or configure using aticonfig.

Now if I try to run aticonfig, it says:

> aticonfig: No supported adapters detected

So. Is this something I should be worried about? Should I have enabled the driver in the Additional Drivers app at all, or is the driver already enabled when I install with the legacy .run file?

EDIT:
Also, now when I try to start Steam I get:

> glXChooseVisual failed

When I check lshw I get this:

> *-display UNCLAIMED
> description: VGA compatible controller
> product: RV710/M92 [Mobility Radeon HD 4330/4350/4550]
> vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
> physical id: 0
> bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
> version: 00
> width: 32 bits
> clock: 33MHz
> capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list
> configuration: latency=0
> resources: memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:4000(size=256) memory:d4000000-d400ffff memory:d4020000-d403ffff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proprietary fglrx driver (which is what you get from Additional Drivers) is not supported anymore by ATI for any ubuntu newer than 12.04.01.  Or for any other linux distro using the same kernel.  You should be using the open source radeon driver.

Comment: Thanks dude. I tried a fresh install now with the newest distro and it works pretty well with the open source radeon driver.